# Boostrap row: get cols within row to be centered?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html:

```
<div class="container cases-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <a href="#" class="case box-link" data-filter="logistics">
          <div class="item1">Something</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <a href="#" class="case box-link" data-filter="construction">
          <div class="item2">Something else</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the columns within my row to be centered, so that even if I have only 1 column it will be in the center of the row instead of aligned to the left.

Is that possible in bootstrap? (Using Bootstrap v3.3.7)

I tried adding `center-block` class to my row, but that had no effect.

**Note:** the number of columns in the row is being generated dynamically.

Comment: add class `col-sm-offset-2` to the first column should center both of them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in that case the centering will not work if I only have 1 column. The number of columns is being generated dynamically.

Comment: Add the class `text-center` to the row, should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follow by adding `col-md-offset-*` to your first col div. Use `*` according to your columns

```css
html {
  background: #ccc;
}
 
[class*='col-'] {
  background: #fff;
}
.col-sm-4{
border:1px solid gray
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-offset-2">
      Column A
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Column B
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-offset-4">
      1 Column Centered
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But what happens when I only have 1 column?

Comment: for single col add `col-md-offset-5` to make it center. Updated that in the code in above snippet. Have a look at it

Comment: @PartisanEntity Please have a look at my code you will get idea about `col-md-offset-*`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem and resolved it with independent CSS
HTML

```
<div class="row center">
```

CSS

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to have the actual columns centered. Not their content.

Comment: <div class="row center"> centers the columns in the row NOT the content of the columns _ 
try it _ it works!

Comment: Why create a new class when bootstrap already offers `text-center`? :-)

Comment: I just tried it and the textual content of the columns is being centered. But both columns remain floating left. I need them to be in centered in the middle of the row though.

Comment: text-center didn't work for me _ not sure why 
I saw your comment higher up the page @swonder and questioned again why it hadn't worked for me _ BS3 'text-center' and my own are same thing _
whatever ; )

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with custom CSS. this will work with **dynamic number of columns**.

- add `center-block` class with `row`
- give `text-align: center;` to `center-block`
- override `float: left;` for `col` classes with `float: none;`
- set `display: inline-block;` for `col` classes so that they align `center`
- for small devices use `@media` and override `display: inline-block;` to `display: block` for `col` classes
- check `code snippet` in **full-page** to see it in action

```css
.center-block {
    text-align: center;
}

.center-block [class*="col-"] {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

/* For small devices */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .center-block [class*="col-"] {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container cases-container">
    <div class="row center-block">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <a href="#" class="case box-link" data-filter="logistics">
          <p>Something</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <a href="#" class="case box-link" data-filter="construction">
          <p>Something else</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PartisanEntity please check my updated answer. hope that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@PartisanEntity, You can apply some logic there. I think you have a total number of columns and you already know the size of your column. Then you can set the offset dynamically.

Let assume

```
total_number_of_columns = 2;

size_of_columns = 4;
```

then calculate the offset and make it round down

```
result_offset_temp = 12 - (total_number_of_columns * size_of_columns );
result_offset = round(result_offset_temp / 2);
```

just put this value as the offset

for example :

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- loop start -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-{ result_offset }">
    <a href="#" class="case box-link" data-filter="logistics">
      <div class="item1">Something</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- loop end -->
</div>
```